# php require file class namespace not works

Tags: php, namespaces, include, require

I have two Class. I want to run these classes by including Foo in Bar class.
It works well without the namespace.

```
<?php

class Foo
{

    public static function test()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

app.php

```
Foo::test();
```

Bar Class

```
class Bar
{

    public function run()
    {
        require('app.php');
    }
}



$bar = new Bar();
$bar->run();
```

When I use Namespace, it does not work.

```
<?php
namespace example;

class Foo{

    public static function test(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

app.php

```
Foo::test();
```

Bar Class

```
namespace example;

use example\Foo;

class Bar{

    public function run(){
     Foo::test(); // its works
         require('app.php'); //  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo' not found
    }
}


$bar = new \example\Bar();
$bar->run();
```

It works when I add namespace to the app.php file.

app.php

```
use example\Foo;
Foo::test();
```

Is there a way to run the file without adding a namespace?

I wrote in English by translating. I hope you understand.

Comment: namespaces are per file as your seeing when you don't add it, you could do `\example\Foo::test();`

Comment: Yes, it will work in writing but you will have to write for each line. Thank you.

Comment: Or use a namespace, there is no workaround, either use a namespace or declare the full path in the call. Think about how confusing and illogical it would be if it wasn't that way, if you `require('app.php');` in namespace `Bar`, then you would have an error it not define, then you would need to define it again in `Bar`, then your be asking why does it not use the other one.. or you would be defining Foo class all over the place..

Comment: require previous Foo::test() works but I am very surprised that Foo::test() in require function does not work. Thank you.